# querying ISODate from unix timestamp in MongoExport

Tags: mongodb, date, timestamp, mongoexport

I'm currently facing a problem to export using the tool mongoexport.

Impossible de to create a date from a timestamp in my query :

```
db.getCollection('FooBarBarFoo').find({"actKey":"foobar","dt":{$gt:new Date('1434907890000')}})
```

Here some tests I made :

```
mongo-aws-dev:SECONDARY> var testDate = new Date('1434907890000');
mongo-aws-dev:SECONDARY> testDate
ISODate("0NaN-NaN-NaNTNaN:NaN:NaNZ")
mongo-aws-dev:SECONDARY> var testDate = new ISODate('1434907890000');
mongo-aws-dev:SECONDARY> testDate
ISODate("1441-08-17T00:00:00Z")
mongo-aws-dev:SECONDARY> var testDate = new ISODate(1434907890000);
mongo-aws-dev:SECONDARY> testDate
ISODate("1441-08-17T00:00:00Z")
```

We can see that the timestamp in millesconds `1434907890000` corresponding to the date `6/21/2015, 7:31:30 PM` in my timezone is converted to some medieval times.

Where can I possibly get wrong and how, in shell script, can I pass the timestamp to mongo query ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Wo, sorry, I've just find the problem.

I tested

- `Date(timestamp in string)`
- `ISODate(timestamp in string)`
- `ISODate(timestamp in number)`

But I didn't test the last ... The right one :

- `Date(timestamp in number)`

So the right query is :

`db.getCollection('FooBarBarFoo').find({"actKey":"foobar","dt":{$gt:new Date(1434907890000)}})`